# Does un-initialized variables in actionscript3 suck up RAM spaces?

Tags: actionscript-3

For example, if I have two classes called `_Sub_class` and `MainClass`

```
class _Sub_class{
    ...
    var test:int;
    var test2:int;
    function _Sub_class(){
        ....
    }
}
```

and

```
class MainClass{
    ...
    var test3:_Sub_class;
    ...
    //And never do: test3 = new _Sub_Class();
}
```

Does `test3` take up the same space as when it's initialized?
(i.e. when a function inside MainClass call the initialize function for the `test3` variable?)

Answer (score 1):

No, it's just a null reference.  It takes up a little space, but not nearly as much as an instance of the class would.

Comment: Thanks Staub :) and BTW, I thought only wikipedia had "citation needed" kk

Comment: I'm not so sure about this. The memory location for the object would have to be allocated null or not. It would be stupid to allocate a small memory block for an object that was not initialized and then have to reallocate more memory once the constructor has been called

Comment: @The: I suspect that you haven't worked with any languages that use references, or weren't aware of it.  See e.g. this [Wikipedia reference-reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28computer_science%29).  "The memory location for the object would have to be allocated null or not." is not true for a reference.

Comment: @Ed I see nothing in that wiki referring to the size of memory used with a null object. And to answer your question yes I have. No matter how Fortran or any other languages handle object pointers and null object it is not ActionScript and you can not say AS3 handles it in the same manner. Don't get confused with memory pointers and object references. var foo:Moo; foo is a reference to a pointer for a block of memory where the Moo object is located. Here I did not use the new constructor and so the object in that memory location is null, but there is still an object there.

Comment: Now the question is how much memory has been allocated.

Comment: @The: We part ways when you refer to a "null object".  I believe that there is no such concept - only a null reference.  You'll find no such concept in the Wikipedia article.  The space required for a reference - null or not - is small.

Comment: @The: Correction: there probably is a null object.  But it's a singleton.

Comment: Ok ED let me clarify then by what I am talking about. A "null" object is an un-instantiated object. Basically a var that has been type cast to a class without using the "new" keyword. Is that clear enough? It will have null value but yet still be type cast and have a pointer to a memory location.

Comment: @The: Yes, it should be in the 4 to 8-byte range, as Cameron noted.  I believe that what you mean by "object" is "a var of type object".  They're not at all the same thing.  When an object is assigned to another var, there are two variables, but only one object.

Comment: This is OOP we are talking about. An object is a class not the object class. For example a button is an object of class Button.

Answer (score 1):

No. Variables in ActionScript are [always just references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActionScript#Using_data_types), which means they are essentially just pointers behind the scenes (probably 4 bytes each of memory use).

The object, when it's been created, will take up space in memory, but the variable you "store"  the object in will remain a constant size, since it's only storing a *reference* to that object.

No space is reserved for the object until it's actually newed up.